# Cumulative distance formula

Tags: velocity, vectors

I am working with position recordings over time. Basically, I record the position of animals in a treadmill. They can go forwards or backwards. Hence, position can increase or decrease. However, I am interested in the total displacement of the animals in a period of time.

From the original position recording I compute the absolute change (absolute velocity, I use `diff` in `R` that basically subtracts row i+1 - row i for every column) and then I go back to cumulate position making the first row zero for all the recordings and adding the row i and i+1 (this is how `diffinv` function in `R` works by default and I want that because scales are different, some annimals (i. e, X0 may be -300 or 17000 for different animals)).
Here is a toy example with first column of matrix `ma` being the time and the three other columns being position recordings from 3 animals.

```
> ma
     time   X1   X2   X3
[1,]    1    0    2    9
[2,]    2    0    5    7
[3,]    3    0    7    5
[4,]    4    0    9    2
```

If I do the plot position vs time

[image]

Since I do not care the about the direction, I work with absolute displacement.
This is the result after cumulative distance calculation. Again, first column is time, 3 other columns are the recordings, now

```
    time V2 V3 V4
1      1  0  0  0
2      2  0  3  2
3      3  0  5  4
4      4  0  7  7
```

This is the plot

My question is.

**How can I express mathematically the operation?** It is not necessary to have the matrix operation. **Mainly I want to say, for each animal (V1,V2,...) the cumulative position in time = t[i] was ______forumula__________**

[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Physics Stack Exchange. This looks more like a problem for [Math SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/), and you might want to move it there. In addition, you need to be clearer about just what you are doing and what you are looking for, preferably near the top of the question.

Comment: @DanielGriscom I was indeed in doubt about here or Math SE. I'll try to edit my question to be more clear. If you think it should be redirected, could you flag for it ?

Comment: I'm not yet omnipotent enough to vote for moving a question. The easiest path is probably just to a) sign up for Math SE, b) copy all the text from this question, c) paste it into a new question at Math SE (perhaps with a note that you're hand-moving it from Physics SE), and d) delete this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from position measurements $x[i]$ taken at times $t[i]$, the total distance travelled is given by
$$d[i] = \sum_{j=0}^{i-1}\left|x[j+1] - x[j]\right|$$
or, equivalently
$$d[i] = \sum_{j=0}^{i-1}\left|\Delta x[j]\right|$$
where $\Delta x[j] = x[j+1] - x[j]$. Note the absolute values in the sum formulas.

Comment: Great. I was wondering, for x=x0; d should be zero. should I define this case separately? i-1 would be -1 in that case and that recording does not exist

Comment: A separate note that $d[0] = 0$ is fine.